# Get current pthread cpu usage Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos, pthreads, cpu-usage

How can I get a thread's cpu time from the thread itself in Mac OS X ? For linux, what I do is `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &ru)` but this solution isn't available for Mac OS X.

I came across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543157/how-can-i-find-out-how-much-memory-my-c-app-is-using-on-the-mac) but I don't know how to adapt it for my purpose (I'm not familiar with Mac OS X's internals. I am not even sure pthread thread == mach thread).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I ended up with:

```
#include <mach/mach_init.h>
#include <mach/thread_act.h>
#include <mach/mach_port.h>
```

[...]

```
mach_port_t thread;
kern_return_t kr;
mach_msg_type_number_t count;
thread_basic_info_data_t info;

thread = mach_thread_self();

count = THREAD_BASIC_INFO_COUNT;
kr = thread_info(thread, THREAD_BASIC_INFO, (thread_info_t) &info, &count);

if (kr == KERN_SUCCESS && (info.flags & TH_FLAGS_IDLE) == 0) {
    usage->utime.tv_sec  = info.user_time.seconds;
    usage->utime.tv_usec = info.user_time.microseconds;
    usage->stime.tv_sec  = info.system_time.seconds;
    usage->stime.tv_usec = info.system_time.microseconds;
}
else {
    // should not happen
    printf("Could not retreive thread info.");
    bzero(usage, sizeof(struct usage));
}

mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), thread);
```

I get very different results that what i get with `getrusage(RUSAGE_THREAD, &ru)` under Linux. So I'm not sure this is the right way.

Comment: The last line isn't correct though, one should do `mach_port_deallocate(mach_task_self(), thread);` instead. That will really decrease the reference count.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the pthread api anyway, his should do the job as well:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <libproc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

[...]

```
uint64_t tid;
pthread_threadid_np(NULL, &tid);
struct proc_threadinfo pth;
if (PROC_PIDTHREADINFO_SIZE ==
      proc_pidinfo(getpid(), PROC_PIDTHREADID64INFO, tid, &pth,
                   PROC_PIDTHREADINFO_SIZE)) {
  printf("user time in ns: %llu\nsystem time in ns: %llu\n",
         pth.pth_user_time, pth.pth_system_time);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can portably use `clock_gettime(3)` with the `CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` clock. Minimally:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// ...

void print_thread_usage(void) {
    struct timespec cpu;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &cpu);
    printf("used %.6f seconds\n", cpu.tv_sec + cpu.tv_nsec/1e9f);
}
```

Available since MacOS 10.12 (2016) and Linux 2.6.12 (2005).